# How to maintain order with finditer ()

Tags: python, regex

There seem to be some problem with finditer(), I am repeatedly searching for a pattern in a line using finditer() and I need to maintain the order in which they are gathered, following is my code for it,

```
 names = collections.OrderedDict()
 line1 = 'XPAC3出口$<zho>$ASDSA1出口$<chn>$ExitA2$<eng>$YUTY1出口$<fre>' 
 names = {n.group(2):n.group(1) for n in re.finditer("\$?(.*?)\$<(.*?)>", line1, re.UNICODE)}
```

And then I am printing it out,

```
for key, value in names.iteritems():
print key, ' ',value
```

And the output turns out to be

fre   YUTY1出口

chn   ASDSA1出口

zho   XPAC3出口

eng   ExitA2

But I need the following order,

zho   XPAC3出口

chn   ASDSA1出口

eng   ExitA2

fre   YUTY1出口

How to go ahead? DO i need to change regex or use something other than finditer()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You rewrite the names dictionary with your dictionary comprehension and regular dictionary doesnt preserve the insert order. To preserve the order return list and give it to `OrderedDict` like this:

```
import collection
import re

line1 = 'XPAC3出口$<zho>$ASDSA1出口$<chn>$ExitA2$<eng>$YUTY1出口$<fre>' 
names = [(n.group(2), n.group(1)) for n in re.finditer("\$?(.*?)\$<(.*?)>", line1, re.UNICODE)]
names = collections.OrderedDict(names)

for key, value in names.iteritems():
    print key, ' ',value
```

Comment: I don't post untested code, it produces the output you need.

Answer (score 3):

When you say

```
names = {...}
```

You are dropping the reference to the empty `OrderedDict` (which will be garbage collected) and rebinding `names` to a regular `dict` (which is unordered of course)

You should pass your matches to the constructor of the OrderedDict

```
names = collections.OrderedDict((n.group(2), n.group(1)) for n in re.finditer("\$?(.*?)\$<(.*?)>", line1, re.UNICODE))
```